# Is it possible to include remote JMX values on a dashboard?

Tags: hawtio

I'm looking at using hawtio for our app as a support console. We're not currently using camel or the like, but I am impressed by the ability to connect to remote JVM's via Jolokia/JMX and the logging features and was wondering:

Our use case would be that we have a weblogic server hosting our web app and my thought would be to include hawtio as a war alongside it. In addition to monitoring the web app, we have a number other JVMs running on different servers.

Is it possible to create a dashboard using values from the local JVM, as well as some of the remote JVMs?

Or must one always manually connect to the instance to see the dashboard for that particular JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current dashboard and JMX plugin does not support that.

Though there is works planned to support gathering statistics from remote JMVs etc. And there is also work on elastichsarch with a kibana web ui.

Comment: But I guess there isn't anything stopping me from creating something to go query those other JVMS, and add the results to JMX Beans in the local JVM - Then add those local beans to the dashboard?

Comment: yeah sure that would be possible. The dashboard can work with any MBean it can find in the JVM.